# What's the point?

Tags: code-golf, math, number, arithmetic

Write a program or function that takes in two integers that represent the X and Y coordinates of a point on a [Cartesian plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system).

The input may come in any reasonable format as long as the X value comes before the Y. For example, `1 -2`, `(1,-2)`, `[1, -2]`, or `1\n-2` would all be fine for X = 1, Y = -2.

Print or return a single character string (followed by an optional trailing newline) that describes the location of the point in the plane:

- `1` if the point is in [quadrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrant_(plane_geometry)) I
- `2` if the point is in quadrant II
- `3` if the point is in quadrant III
- `4` if the point is in quadrant IV
- `X` if the point is on the x-axis (lowercase `x` is not allowed)
- `Y` if the point is on the y-axis (lowercase `y` is not allowed)
- `O` if the point is on the origin (that's a capital letter "oh", not zero)

**The shortest code in bytes wins.** Tiebreaker goes to the higher voted answer.

### Test Cases

```
(1,-2) -> 4
(30,56) -> 1
(-2,1) -> 2
(-89,-729) -> 3
(-89,0) -> X
(0,400) -> Y
(0,0) -> O
(0,1) -> Y
(0,-1) -> Y
(1,0) -> X
(-1,0) -> X
(1,1) -> 1
(1,-1) -> 4
(-1,1) -> 2
(-1,-1) -> 3
```

Comment: So for the purposes of this challenge, X and Y axis are in no quadrant?

Comment: @RikerW Right. Otherwise the point (0, 9) could be said to be quadrant I or II.

Comment: Is a complex number (or a string representation of it, like `"30+56i"`) a valid input format?

Comment: @steveverrill Yes

Comment: Can the input be in the form of a complex number? (e.g. `1+2j`)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Jelly, 14 bytes

```
Ṡḅ3ị“Y4X13X2YO
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bmg4biFM-G7i-KAnFk0WDEzWDJZTw&input=&args=LTEsLTE)

#### How it works

```
Ṡḅ3ị“Y4X13X2YO    Main link. Input: [x, y]

Ṡ                 Apply the sign function to both coordinates.
 ḅ3               Convert the resulting pair from base 3 to integer.
                  Because of how base conversion is implemented in Jelly, this maps
                  [a, b] to (3a + b), even if a and b aren't valid ternary digits.
                  Therefore:
                      [0, 1]   ->  1
                      [1, -1]  ->  2
                      [1, 0]   ->  3
                      [1, 1]   ->  4
                      [-1, -1] -> -4
                      [-1, 0]  -> -3
                      [-1, 1]  -> -2
                      [0, -1]  -> -1
                      [0, 0]   ->  0
   ị“Y4X13X2YO    Retrieve the character at that index from the string.
                Indexing is 1-based and modular in Jelly, so 1ị retrieves the
                first character, -1ị the penultimate, and 0ị the last.
```

Comment: Joining the *Jelly from phone* club.

Comment: Aaaaaand Jelly wins once again...

Comment: Very good approach!

Answer (score 11):

### Ruby, 35 bytes

```ruby
->x,y{%w[OY X14 X23][x<=>0][y<=>0]}
```

Leveraging the "spaceship" (`<=>`) operator.

`x <=> 0` will return

- `0` if `x == 0`
- `1` if `x > 0`
- `-1` if `x < 0`

Hence,

- if `x == 0`, we return `'OY'[y<=>0]`. This is

  - `O` if `y == 0` (string indexing at `0`)
  - `Y` if `y != 0` (this is true because both `1` and `-1` will result in `Y` when indexing on this string, as `-1` refers to the last character in the string, which also happens to be the one at index 1)
- if `x > 0`, we return `'X14'[y<=>0]`. This is `X` if `y == 0`, `1` if `y > 0`, and `4` if `y < 0` (see explanation above).
- if `x < 0`, we return `'X23'[y<=>0]`.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript, 44 bytes

```
(x,y)=>x?y?x>0?y>0?1:4:y>0?2:3:'X':y?'Y':'O'
```

```js
f=(x,y)=>x?
            y?
                x>0?
                    y>0?1
                    :4
                :y>0?2:3
            :'X'
        :y?'Y':'O'

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' +
    'f(1,-2) -> ' + f(1,-2) + '<br>' +
    'f(30,56) -> ' + f(30,56) + '<br>' +
    'f(-2,1) -> ' + f(-2,1) + '<br>' +
    'f(-89,-729) -> ' + f(-89,-729) + '<br>' +
    'f(-89,0) -> ' + f(-89,0) + '<br>' +
    'f(0,400) -> ' + f(0,400) + '<br>' +
    'f(0,0) -> ' + f(0,0) + '<br>' +
    'f(0,1) -> ' + f(0,1) + '<br>' +
    'f(0,-1) -> ' + f(0,-1) + '<br>' +
    'f(1,0) -> ' + f(1,0) + '<br>' +
    'f(-1,0) -> ' + f(-1,0) + '<br>' +
    'f(1,1) -> ' + f(1,1) + '<br>' +
    'f(1,-1) -> ' + f(1,-1) + '<br>' +
    'f(-1,1) -> ' + f(-1,1) + '<br>' +
    'f(-1,-1) -> ' + f(-1,-1) + '<br>' +
'</pre>';
```

Comment: My eyes hurt, that's one long chain of ternary operators

Comment: afaik its allowed to write an anonymous function (`s/^f=//`)

Answer (score 5):

### ES6, 43 bytes

```
(x,y)=>"OYYX32X41"[3*!!x+3*(x>0)+!!y+(y>0)]
```

A whole byte shorter than all of those ternaries!

Answer (score 3):

## Japt, <s>30</s> 22 bytes

```
"3Y2XOX4Y1"g4+3*Ug +Vg
```

Inspired by @Dennis' Jelly answer before he added an explanation. [Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=IjNZMlhPWDRZMSJnNCszKlVnICtWZw==&input=MSwgMQ==)

Fun fact: this would be two bytes shorter if I had added support for negative numbers in the `g` function for strings.

Another attempt, closer to the Jelly one (23 bytes):

```
"3Y2XOX4Y1"gNmg m+1 ¬n3
```

Sadly, incrementing a list costs 4 bytes...

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 22 bytes

```
'3X2YOY4X1'iZSQI1h*sQ)
```

This uses [current release (10.2.1)](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/releases/tag/10.2.1) of the language/compiler.

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=JzNYMllPWTRYMSdpWlNRSTFoKnNRKQ&input=Wy04OSwgMF0)

#### Explanation

This shamelessly borrows the great approach in [Dennis' answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70485/36398).

```
'3X2YOY4X1'     % literal string. Will be indexed into to produce result
i               % input array of two numbers
ZS              % sign of each number in that array. Gives -1, 0 or 1
Q               % add 1 to produce 0, 1 or 2
I1h             % array [3 1]
*s              % multiply both arrays element-wise and compute sum
Q               % add 1. Gives a value from 1 to 9
)               % index into string. Display
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 18 bytes

```
@"OY4X13X2Y"i._RQ3
```

Explanation:

```
                   - Autoassign Q = eval(input())
             ._RQ  - map(cmp, Q)
            i    3 - convert to base 3
@"OY4X13X2Y"       - "OY4X13X2Y"[^] (A lookup table)
```

[Try it here.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%40%22OY4X13X2Y%22i._RQ3&input=%28-89%2C-729%29&test_suite_input=%281%2C-2%29+%0A%2830%2C56%29%0A%28-2%2C1%29+%0A%28-89%2C-729%29%0A%28-89%2C0%29+%0A%280%2C400%29+%0A%280%2C0%29%0A%280%2C1%29%0A%280%2C-1%29%0A%281%2C0%29%0A%28-1%2C0%29+%0A%281%2C1%29%0A%281%2C-1%29+%0A%28-1%2C1%29+%0A%28-1%2C-1%29+&debug=0)

[Or the whole test suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%40%22OY4X13X2Y%22i._RQ3&input=%28-89%2C-729%29&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%281%2C-2%29+%0A%2830%2C56%29%0A%28-2%2C1%29+%0A%28-89%2C-729%29%0A%28-89%2C0%29+%0A%280%2C400%29+%0A%280%2C0%29%0A%280%2C1%29%0A%280%2C-1%29%0A%281%2C0%29%0A%28-1%2C0%29+%0A%281%2C1%29%0A%281%2C-1%29+%0A%28-1%2C1%29+%0A%28-1%2C-1%29+&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, 75 bytes

```
lambda x,y,b=bool:[['OX','YO'][b(y)][b(x)],[[1,2],[4,3]][y<0][x<0]][b(x*y)]
```

Pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica 81 bytes

```
Switch[Sign@#,{1,-1},4,{1,1},1,{-1,1},2,{-1,-1},3,{0,0},"O",{_,0},"X",{0,_},"Y"]&
```

---

```
%/@{{1, -2}, {30, 56}, {-2, 1}, {-89, -729}, {-89, -0}, {0, 400}, {0, 0},{0, 1}, {0, -1}, {1, 0}, {-1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, -1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, -1}}
```

> {4, 1, 2, 3, "X", "Y", "O", "Y", "Y", "X", "X", 1, 4, 2, 3}

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 52

This is a simple substitution-based method:

```
^0 0
O
^0.*
Y
.* 0
X
-.*-.*
3
^-.*
2
.*-.*
4
.* .*
1
```

[Try it online](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=bWBeMCAwCk8KbWBeMC4qClkKbWAuKiAwClgKLS4qLS4qCjMKbWBeLS4qCjIKLiotLioKNAouKiAuKgox&input=MSAtMgozMCA1NgotMiAxCi04OSAtNzI5Ci04OSAwCjAgNDAwCjAgMAowIDEKMCAtMQoxIDAKLTEgMAoxIDEKMSAtMQotMSAxCi0xIC0x).  The extra `` m` ``  at the start of some lines is only needed to test multiple inputs in one go, so are not counted in the score.

---

Previously I tried [this more interesting approach](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=WzEtOV1cZCoKMQotMQoyCiguKSAoLikKJDEkKjMkMiQqMQozCjExMQptYF4oLikqJAokIzEKVGBkYE9ZWVgxNFgyMw&input=MSAtMgozMCA1NgotMiAxCi04OSAtNzI5Ci04OSAwCjAgNDAwCjAgMAowIDEKMCAtMQoxIDAKLTEgMAoxIDEKMSAtMQotMSAxCi0xIC0x), but its quite a bit longer (about 65 without the `m` modifiers):

```
[1-9]\d*
1
-1
2
(.) (.)
$1$*3$2$*1
3
111
m`^(.)*$
$#1
T`d`OYYX14X23
```

- substitute all non-zero numbers to `1`, leaving `-` signs in place
- Substitute `-1` with `2`
- Convert 1st and 2nd numbers unary with `3` and `1` respectively as the unary digits .  This effectively gives 2 base3 digits, expressed in unary
- Convert to `3`s to `111`.  This effectively gives the a single unary number that corresponds to each of the quadrants, axes and origin
- Convert the unary to one decimal digit
- Transpose the decimal digit to the appropriate output char.

Comment: I don't think the `X` stage needs `$` since there won't be leading zeroes in the input.

Comment: The more interesting approach can be [shortened to at least 40 bytes](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=MAoKXGQrCi0KIAokYCRgCl4oLikqJAokIzEKVGBkYE9ZWVgxNFgyMw&input=MSAtMg). Now I will look at it tomorrow some more.

Comment: For batch run you [need some tweaking](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=MAoKXGQrCi0KKD88PSguKikpIAokMSQxCm1gXiguKSokCiQjMQpUYGRgT1lZWDE0WDIz&input=MSAtMgozMCA1NgotMiAxCi04OSAtNzI5Ci04OSAwCjAgNDAwCjAgMAowIDEKMCAtMQoxIDAKLTEgMAoxIDEKMSAtMQotMSAxCi0xIC0x).

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 24

Too long, but perhaps an interesting approach:

```
?Q?sQ?eQh%/yPQ.n04\X\Y\O
```

The input must be specified as a complex number, e.g. `1-2j`.  Basically a nested ternary to test:

- if input is zero - output `O`
- else if real part is zero - output `Y`
- else if imaginary part is zero - output `X`
- else calculate the complex phase, multiply by 2, integer divide by π, then mod and add to give the appropriate quadrant number.

[Try it online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3FQ%3FsQ%3FeQh%25%2FyPQ.n04%5CX%5CY%5CO&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1-2j%0A30%2B56j%0A-2%2B1j%0A-89-729j%0A-89%2B0j%0A0%2B400j%0A0%2B0j%0A0%2B1j%0A0-1j%0A1%2B0j%0A-1%2B0j%0A1%2B1j%0A1-1j%0A-1%2B1j%0A-1%2B-1j&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, 34 bytes

```
@(p)['3X2YOY4X1'](sign(p)*[3;1]+5)
```

The old base-3 trick through vector multiplication (although I had to add 5 to account for 1-based array indices) plus some Octave indexing magic.

Input is a vector of the form `[1, -2]` (with or without the comma), so when assigned to a variable `w`:

```
>> w([1 -2])
ans = 4
```

Here it is on [ideone](http://ideone.com/oYfMNO).

Comment: Ideone seems to be working again. Did you do anything special to use it?

Comment: @LuisMendo This one uses an anonymous function. Named functions are still borked for me. :(

Comment: Aah, you are right. It was named functions that were not working. So still the same :-/

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 64 bytes

this is a lambda expression for a `BiFunction<Integer,Integer,String>`.

```
(x,y)->"OYYX14X23".charAt(3*(x>0?1:x<0?2:0)+(y>0?1:y<0?2:0))+"";
```

3 bytes could be saved by returning a `Character` instead of a `String` but i'm not completely sure if autoboxing will play nicely with the lambda.

Comment: Oh neat, this answer using the [PCCG Handicap System](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71117/the-ppcg-handicap-system) scores better (1.5598) than Dennis's Jelly answer (1.5929).

Comment: that's quite interesting. thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Ran the values for a few entries on this one out of curiosity (all scores were between 1.5 and 2, for reference).